# Are IP addresses in 0.0.0.0/8 essentially private IP addresses, although not said to be?

Tags: ip-address

0.0.0.0/8 is said to be the current network. Are the IP addresses in the range not public available?  Are they essentially private IP addresses, although not said to be?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The IANA registry of IPv4 addresses refers to RFC 1122 for 0.0.0.0/8.  RFC 1122 defines the addresses in that block in section 3.2.1.3, note that it was written in the classful era, so some translation is needed to translate it to modern terminology.

First the definition of 0.0.0.0/32 (in classful terminlogy network number 0, host number 0)

```
(a)  { 0, 0 }
   This host on this network.  MUST NOT be sent, except as
   a source address as part of an initialization procedure
   by which the host learns its own IP address.
```

In practice this address is widely used for DHCP, it is also used in the sockets API as a wildcard address to specify "any interface". Some implementations also treat an attempt to send packets or make a connection to 0.0.0.0 the same as attempting to send them to the loopback address.

Now lets look at the rest of 0.0.0.0/8 (in classful terminology network number 0)

```
(b)  { 0, <Host-number> }
   Specified host on this network.  It MUST NOT be sent,
   except as a source address as part of an initialization
   procedure by which the host learns its full IP address.
```

So in principle if you had a network with a static mapping between network-specific addresses and the host part of IP addresses you could use addresses from 0.0.0.0/8 as the source addresses during an initialization process to find the network part of the IP address.

In practice that is rarely if ever done. While static mappings between network-specific addresses and Internet addresses were a thing in the early days of the Internet they are basically unheard of nowadays.

---

> Are the IP addresses in the range not public available?

They are not used on the public Internet.

> Are they essentially private IP addresses, although not said to be?

Not really.

Yes their intended use is local to a given network, but their intended use is very specific. They are not intended to be used as general purpose private addresses.

You might ask "since noone uses them for their original purpose and they are not used for anything on the Internet why not ignore the RFC and use them as general purpose private addresses?".

And the answer to that one is "unfortunately the implementations won't let you".

Answer (score 6):

The `0.0.0.0/8` block is reserved by ARIN, see [RFC 1122](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc1122). (Peter's answer explains the RFC's terminology very well, please read & appreciate.)

`0.0.0.0/32` may be temporarily used [edit] *as source address* for acquiring a local IP address over the network via DHCP and the like.

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate more about the two? the first one is the current network, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Special-use_addresses

Comment: Just to comment on the DHCP use: it's only used as the source address from a host which has not yet been allocated an IP address; not a destination address, as messges from the DHCP server are broadcast to 255.255.255.255.  See RFC 2131 s4.1

Comment: @Tim, the RFCs, not Wikipedia, are the standards. When in doubt, check the RFCs. There are only three ranges of Private IPv4 addresses (IPv6 doesn't have Private addressing). You can see the Special IPv4 address ranges at _[IANA IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml)_.